# Joomla registration error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

In the website http://www.ple-intl.com/NewUpgrade, I am using joomla 2.5 & getting an below error during registration

- It registered the user but, does not send the activation link, however it is set as a self in user options.
- when user click on register after filling form it shows an 404 error. (personally i dont change any thing core, & i dont want to but i am getting an error i checked all the things)

**Some Plugin Information**

- I installed virtue mart in it, but every thing is defualt
- I am user Super Login Module for login registration which calls the default joomla signup page.

Kindly guide what i am missing..I am tired to sort that out but none of my idea works.

Comment: Does the registration from the Joomla default component work? It seems like you have issues with this "super login module" (which I know nothing of).

Comment: @RiccardoZorn no it is not after when user click on the registration it shows error on this link
index.php/component/users/?task=registration.register

Comment: @RiccardoZorn i disabled that module but no good luck

Comment: try to disable SEF (from control panel/global configuration) and cache (system plugin cache), if it still doesn't work put it in debug mode and post the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks it start working now, below i have mentioned the reason why it showing error.

- The email i was inserted is actually  registered before & when i remove that id i did'not remove the product related to it in virtue mart.
- second virtue mart registration activation link which send in email has some problems, on the below link solution is discussed.
  http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=99755.0